# Executing Azure CLI from shell script as cron job

Tags: linux, node.js, shell, azure, cron

Inside the shell script sing the full path to the Azure CLI & Node JS.

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/nodejs/bin/node /opt/nodejs/bin/azure vm disk list > /tmp/tmpfile

/opt/nodejs/bin/node /opt/nodejs/bin/azure vm disk upload $SRCURL $DESURL <KEY>
```

When executed manually both the commands are getting executed successfully. But when executed using crontab `vm disk list` command is working but `vm disk upload` is not working.

Azure JS script requires another cli.js which is been referenced through relative path `var AzureCli = require('../lib/cli');` and the cli.js script requires lots of other scripts which is been referenced through relative path.

Is there any way to provide the same environment profile as the user to cron hence it works or is there any best way to make this work without editing individual JS file and rename the relative path to absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was because the `HOME` environment variable was not getting set when executed through `cron` and that was causing the Azure command to fail.

When the `HOME` variable is set to the specific user's home directory in the script, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your path of required file in PATH environment variable in /etc/profile file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path to your files
```

Comment: Strangely `PATH` is not a problem here. I validated that `PATH` variable contains the same paths when I execute it manually or through cron. Problem here is Node JS is not able to identify the relative path of the library files required by various .js files. If there is some option to specify the library location for Node JS similar to Perl/Ruby it would resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

just redeclare environment variable inside the cron.

example crontab:

```
NODE_ENV=production
* * * * * /bin/sh /path/to/your/shellscript/nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for environment variable `SHELL=/bin/sh`.
Most times `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/bash`, but on Ubuntu `/bin/sh` is a symbolic link to `/bin/dash`:

```
$ ls -la /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 feb 19  2014 /bin/sh -> dash
```

So in this case you need to redeclare this environment variable:

```
export SHELL=/bin/bash
```

In my case, I export the environment variable in my script and have the following in crontab:

```
# run azure test every 5 minutes
*/5 * * * * /opt/bin/azure-test >/tmp/azure-test.out 2>&1
```